# Can not access the values of iterator

Tags: java, list, mapreduce, iterator

I am working on the word count example in map-reduce with some modifications. I am copying values of the iterator in the reducer to a list to check whether the numbers are positive or negative to sum them each separately. The problem is I can not get the values when they are stored in the list. I get zeroes as the total of the sum, something like this:

```
Hello 0
World 0
```

The code of the reducer:

```
     public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements   Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
         public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
         int sum = 0;
         int listSize=0;
         boolean isPos=false;
         boolean isNeg=false;
         List<Integer> l=new ArrayList<Integer>();
         int size=Iterators.size(values);

         while (values.hasNext()) {
             l.add(values.next().get());
         }

         for(int i=0; i<l.size();i++) {
             if(l.get(i)==-1) {isNeg=true;}
             else if(isNeg!=true && l.get(i)!=-1) isPos=true;
         }

         if(isNeg==true) {
             for(int i=0; i<l.size();i++) {
                l.add(i, -1);
             }
         }
         for(int i=0; i<l.size();i++) {
            sum+=l.get(i);
         }
         if(isNeg) {sum=sum+1;}
         if(isPos) {sum=sum-1;}

         if(sum>0) {sum=sum-1;}
         else if (sum<0){sum=sum+1;}

         output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));}
    }
```

When I return the code to this I get the sum of numbers but I can not access the values when copying them to list.

```
while (values.hasNext()) {
         sum+=values.next().get());
     }
```